# AngularJs - $watch only works when Chrome Developer Tools is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to attach a $watch to a directive that watches for when the element's height and width change so that it can use the height and width to center on top of the image.

Here is my app.js code:

```
app.directive('centerElement', function ($timeout) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return { 
                'h': element[0].offsetHeight, 
                'w': element[0].offsetWidth 
            };
        }, 
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var elementHeight = newValue.h;
            var elementWidth = newValue.w;

            /*To account for rounding errors and not loop*/
            if(elementHeight % 2 === 0)
            {
                element.css('margin-top', '-' + ((elementHeight) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            else 
            {
                element.css('margin-top', '-' + ((elementHeight + 1) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            if(elementWidth % 2 === 0)
            {
                element.css('margin-left', '-' + ((elementWidth) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            else
            {
                element.css('margin-left', '-' + ((elementWidth + 1) / 2) + 'px');
            }
        }, true);

        element.bind('centerElement', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
};
});
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="row relativePosition">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 noPadding">
        <img id="getStartedGiveGiftImage" ng-src="{{homeCtrl.getHomeImageBySectionName('getStartedGiveGift').url}}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="getStartedGiveGiftCol" class="absolutePosition" center-element>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="getStartedGiveGiftText headingTitle">
                Swapping, Sharing,
                <div class="getStartedGiveGiftText text-right">
                    and Caring
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="getStartedGiveGiftButtons" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right">
            <div>
                <a id="getStartedGiveGiftButton1" class="btn btn-default text-right redBackgroundGradient" href="{{homeCtrl.getPage('Get Started').route}}">Get Started</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a id="getStartedGiveGiftButton2" class="btn btn-default getStartedGiveGiftButton greenBackgroundGradient text-right text-white" href="{{homeCtrl.getPage('Give a Gift').route}}">Give a Gift</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the css for the .getStartedGiveGiftCol already set to

```
#getStartedGiveGiftCol {
top: 50%;
left: 50%; }
```

Adding `margin-top` and `margin-left` values to half the height and half the width places the element directly in the center of the image.

When I run the the app in Google Chrome without the Developer Tools open, the centerElement directive watch didn't get called when the image loaded and the height and width adjusted on the element, however when I run the app by stepping through Chrome Developer Tools, the element gets centered over the image just fine.  When I open Developer Tools after running the app without it, there are no errors.
Also, I tried running the app in Internet Explorer, Edge, and Firefox.  Internet Explorer and Firefox all acted the same way as Chrome, however, Edge was the only browser that centered the image the way it is supposed to.

I would prefer to not use $watch because it can have performance issues, but from the research I've done in the documentation and on google I haven't been able to figure out another way to do this but I am very open to ideas.  I tried to find something on waiting until the image loads and then centering the element, but I had no luck.  I will be repeating this directive in other parts of the app so it would be awesome to not have to use $watch.

I'm very new to angularJS so any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm also new to asking questions on stackoverflow so if you need anymore information, just let me know.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I created another directive for image, that would call scope.$digest() when it loaded.  It seemed to help, but when I refresh the page multiple times, sometimes it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Here's the directive I added:

```
app.directive('imageOnload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                scope.$digest();
            });
            element.bind('error', function(){
                alert('image could not be loaded');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do this with css alone. Can you create a demo

Comment: I thought the same as you, I found that since the row has `position: relative` and the element I'm trying to center has `position: absolute` it screws up css positioning and the best way to get it to completely center even when the screen gets adjusted is to set `top` and  `left` to `50%` and then to set `margin-left` to negative half the width of the element and `margin-top` to negative half the height of the element.
If I didn't need to use absolute positioning to position the element over the image, then this wouldn't be an issue.
How would I go about creating a demo?

Comment: Here's one of the sources I found the centering absolutely positioned elements at at: http://www.sitepoint.com/css-center-position-absolute-div/

Comment: can use css3 `flexbox` also for centering.

Comment: flexbox screws up bootstrap responsiveness, so that didn't work either.

Comment: well that doesn't make sense either. Why would you need both on that element?

Comment: both what?  The row has relative positioning and the element has absolute positioning.

Comment: I don't have one, and I don't know how to create one.  How would I go about creating a demo?

Comment: fairly easy to load all resources needed into http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own.  I needed to add `$timeout();` to my `centerElement` directive.  This forces a `$scope.$apply();` when the current `$digest` is done so that the changes made in the `$watch` are actually applied to the page.

My directive is below:

```
app.directive('centerElement', function ($timeout) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            $timeout();
            return { 
                'h': element[0].offsetHeight, 
                'w': element[0].offsetWidth 
            };
        }, 
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var elementHeight = newValue.h;
            var elementWidth = newValue.w;

            /*To account for rounding errors and not loop*/
            if(elementHeight % 2 === 0)
            {
                element.css('margin-top', '-' + ((elementHeight) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            else 
            {
                element.css('margin-top', '-' + ((elementHeight + 1) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            if(elementWidth % 2 === 0)
            {
                element.css('margin-left', '-' + ((elementWidth) / 2) + 'px');
            }
            else
            {
                element.css('margin-left', '-' + ((elementWidth + 1) / 2) + 'px');
            }
        }, true);

        element.bind('centerElement', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
};
});
```

If anyone has any ideas of how to avoid using `$watch` let me know.  I can't use CSS only, because the `row` is `position: relative` and the element is `position: absolute` so I have to use `top: 50%`, `left: 50%`, `margin-top` negative and half the height of the element and `margin-left` negative and half the width (i.e. `margin-top: -100px` when the element height is 200px and `margin-left: -50px` when the element width is 100px) in order to center the element on the image.  I needed to find out the width and height of the element rather than hard-coding it into CSS which could be tedious in the future for maintenance purposes since I'd have to figure out the size for all screen sizes for bootstrap.   Hence why I'm using `$watch`.
I'm also using bootstrap, so CSS3 `flexbox` is out of the question because it messes up the bootstrap grid responsiveness.

So if anyone has any ideas how to get rid of the $watch, please let me know.